# Toggling jsxgraph board properties with buttons using angular

Tags: angularjs, jsxgraph

Hi I tried to make a simple jsxgraph plot where I can switch some properties of the board with buttons.
I am using angular but I can't see why it does not work.
Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/joshdmiller/HB7LU/)

I am happy about any kind of help

```
 <div class="col-md-10">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div id="jsxgbox" class="jxgbox " style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="showAxis" ng-click="showAxis = !showAxis">
    <span ng-show="showAxis">axis On</span>
    <span ng-show="!showAxis">axis Off</span></button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="showNav" ng-click="showNav = !showNav"> <span ng-show="showNav">Navigation On</span>
    <span ng-show="!showNav">Navigation Off</span></button>
    </div>
</div>

var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
function MyCtrl($scope) {
$scope.showAxis = true;
$scope.showNav = false;
$scope.axisOn = true
$scope.board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jsxgbox', {
    unitX: 10, // this are the lighter gray lines parallel ro the y axis
    unitY: 10,
    axis: $scope.showAxis,
    showNavigation: $scope.showNav,
    showCopyright: false,
    grid: true,
    wheel: true,
    keepaspectratio: true,
    needshift: false,
    boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5] // upperleft corner ( x1,y1) bottom right corner (x2,y2)
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In JSXGraph, the default axes and the navigation bar behave a little bit different from other elements. The navigation bar can only be switched off by setting directly the CSS attribute to the HTML div. 
Here is a working version of your example. I'm sorry if the code is not polished. This is my first angual.js application. But it is nice to see how JSXGraph and angualrs.jus work together.

```
<!doctype html>
<html ng-app="JSXGraphApp">
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraphcore.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://jsxgraph.uni-bayreuth.de/distrib/jsxgraph.css"/>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="col-md-10">          
        <div ng-controller="JSXGraphController">
            <div id="jsxgbox" class="jxgbox " style="width:250px; height:250px;"></div>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="showAxis" ng-click="toggleAxis()">
                <span ng-show="showAxis">axis On</span>
                <span ng-show="!showAxis">axis Off</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="showNav" ng-click="toggleNav()"> 
                <span ng-show="showNav">Navigation On</span>
                <span ng-show="!showNav">Navigation Off</span>
            </button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-model="showPoint" ng-click="togglePoint()"> 
                <span ng-show="showPoint">Show point</span>
                <span ng-show="!showPoint">Hide point</span>
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>

<script type="text/javascript">

var JSXGraphApp = angular.module('JSXGraphApp', [])
    .controller('JSXGraphController', function($scope) {

    $scope.showAxis = true;
    $scope.showNav = false;
    $scope.showPoint = true;
    $scope.axisOn = true;
    $scope.board = JXG.JSXGraph.initBoard('jsxgbox', {
        unitX: 10, // this are the lighter gray lines parallel ro the y axis
        unitY: 10,
        axis: $scope.showAxis,
        showNavigation: $scope.showNav,
        showCopyright: false,
        grid: true,
        wheel: true,
        keepaspectratio: true,
        needshift: false,
        boundingbox: [-5, 5, 5, -5] // upperleft corner ( x1,y1) bottom right corner (x2,y2)
    });

    $scope.toggleNav = function() {
        var navbar = document.getElementById($scope.board.containerObj.id + '_navigationbar');
        $scope.showNav = !$scope.showNav;
        if ($scope.showNav) {
            navbar.style.display = "block";
        } else {
            navbar.style.display = "none";
        }
    };

    $scope.toggleAxis = function() {
        $scope.showAxis = !$scope.showAxis;
        $scope.board.defaultAxes.x.setAttribute({visible: $scope.showAxis});
        $scope.board.defaultAxes.y.setAttribute({visible: $scope.showAxis});
    };

    $scope.p = $scope.board.create('point', [1, 2]);
    $scope.togglePoint = function() {
        $scope.showPoint = !$scope.showPoint;
        $scope.p.setAttribute({visible: $scope.showPoint});
    };
});
</script>
```

Comment: thank your for your answer, i will look into it and reply a.s.p

Comment: angualjs.didnt hear about it before